# Assigning number of hours since certain date

Tags: javascript

Question:

> Assign hoursPassed with the number of hours passed since Facebook's
>   website launched and today. Hint: 1000 milliseconds are in a second,
>   60 seconds are in a minute, etc.

Code given:

```
var interestingEvents = {
   "Long distance telegraph": new Date(1844, 4, 24),
   "First telephone call": new Date(1876, 2, 10),
   "Microsoft founded": new Date(1975, 3, 4),
   "World wide web born": new Date(1989, 2, 1),
   "Google founded": new Date(1998, 8, 4),
   "Facebook website launch": new Date(2004, 1, 4)
};
var interestingDate = interestingEvents["Facebook website launch"]; // Code also tested using date of First telephone call
var hoursPassed = 0;
```

My code so far:

```
var temp, sec, min;

temp = interestingDate.getTime();

sec = temp / 1000;

min = sec / 60;

hoursPassed= min / 60;
```

Comment: What's your *question*?

Comment: Can you explain what is not currently working in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to calculate the **difference**, subtract the Facebook's launch day from the current date before calculating hours:

```
var temp, sec, min;

temp = new Date() - interestingDate.getTime();

sec = temp / 1000;

min = sec / 60;

hoursPassed = min / 60;
```

Or the above in a single line:

```
var hoursPassed = (new Date() - interestingDate) / 3600000
```

Comment: ah was forgetting the difference. thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad tgat it helped. You can accept tge answer that helped you the most by the gray checkmark next to it

Comment: @godbl3ssyou I'm glad that it helped. You can accept the answer that helped you the most by the gray checkmark next to it